# Is a decimal number, such as 0.345 a fraction?

Tags: fractions

Just by semantics alone, would you consider it a fraction when it is not written in a 'fractional' format?

Comment: What is your definition of fraction?  Does it refer to the notation or to whether the value is rational?

Comment: I think it's pretty standard usage for "fraction" to mean the representation of the number and not the number itself. However, it can at times mean the number itself.

Comment: I'm wondering under the standard, widely believed definition of a fraction, is a number such as 0.233 a fraction.

Comment: Just trying to win an argument with someone else, actually, but I'd like to know too!

Comment: Good luck finding a standard, widely believed definition that is not contradicted by some other standard, widely believed definition.

Comment: 0.345 is a rational number, which means that it can be represented as a fraction.  i.e. $\frac {345}{1000}.$  I would say the number 0.345 is not a fraction if it is not represented as one.

Comment: The Oxford English Dictionary defines *decimal fraction* as "a fraction whose denominator is a power of ten (e.g. 5/100); (in later use also) such a fraction expressed as a decimal (e.g. 0.05)" so I would say yes.

Comment: $0.345$ denotes the fraction $345/1000$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have pointed out in the comments, there may be contradictory definitions, and it depends on what the context is.

That being said, have a look at the description of the tag you used for the question:

> (fractions): *Questions on fractions, i.e. expressions (not values) of the form $\frac ab$, including arithmetic with fractions. Not to be confused with the tag (rational-numbers): fractions denote rational numbers, but the same rational number may be written in different ways as a fraction.*

So $0.345$ is definitely a rational number, but in its current form is not a fraction according to this description.

Comment: Thank you! That's all I need.